# Do shell scripts wait for PHP commands to end before moving onto next line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, shell

If I write a shell script something like this:

```
php script1.php
php script2.php
```

What happens when I run it?  Does shell wait until `script1.php` has finished before moving onto `php script2.php` or does the 2nd line get ran immediately after the first?

If the latter, how can I get it to behave like the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All shell commands are executed sequentially and each command is executed after finishing the previous one unless you run a command in the background by appending ampersand `&` at the end of the command.